# populate barchart by jtable values in java

Tags: java, jtable, jfreechart

I have a jtable I want to display the characters column in the absciss I tried this code by puting each column in an array but it shown nothing, when I debug it doesn't enter in the exception and there are no message in the consol.

```
public void Graph() {
    try {
        DefaultCategoryDataset base = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        Character[] letters = new Character[table.getRowCount()];
        Integer[] frequences = new Integer[table.getRowCount()];

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            letters[i] = (Character) table.getValueAt(i, 0);
            frequences[i] = (Integer) table.getValueAt(i, 1);
            base.setValue(frequences[i], "Fréquences", letters[i]);
        }

        JFreeChart graph = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(
                "Diagramme des Fréquences",//titre
                "Lettres", //abscisses
                "Fréquences", //ordonnées
                base, //data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                false, //legende
                true, //tooltips
                false //URLs
        );
        ChartPanel Panel = new ChartPanel(graph);
        panelGraph.removeAll();
        panelGraph.add(Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelGraph.validate();
        CategoryPlot p = graph.getCategoryPlot();
        // set the range axis to display integers only...
        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) p.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

the jtable is populated when running but the graph doesn't appear

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Oracles implementation of bar charts in JavaFX 8:
[Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/bar-chart.htm#CIHJFHDE)

If you do not want to use JavaFX 8 for your whole application, you can also implement it in Swing using the `JFXPanel`:[Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)

Comment: I don't know what is javaFX technologie I'm debutant in java, but I tried something else, I extract data from the hashmap into 2 arrays and try to populate the graph but I have ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784 This should explain what JavaFX is. Brief description: Since Java 8 it's the recommend API to create user interfaces. Its predecessor was Swing, which i guess you are using.